# This Page isn't working Localhost redirected too many times MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

[image: Too many redirects]

[image: Error with many encoded ReturnUrl parameters]

Program.cs File with Cookie authentication:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("CookieAuthentication").AddCookie("CookieAuthentication", options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/<Login/LoginView";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/AccessDenied";
            });

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Login}/{action=Signup}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

Login Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult LoginView(string username, string password)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //Error code here
            }
            
            if (!UserExists(username, password))//Check if user exists in Database
            {
                //Error code here
            }
           
            TempData["Username"] = username;
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            //I used breakpoint here and this code runs but doesn't work properly.
        }
```

I have also used the [Authorize] attribute on Home Controller to prevent users from accessing it without login.Login/LoginView is the Login rage Path.

Comment: You said you add the `[Authorize]` attribute on HomeController? Please be sure add the `[AllowAnonymous]` on the Index action in HomeController. Because for your url, it seems always redirect to the `Home/Index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This Page isn't working Localhost redirected too many times MVC

For your current scenario,be sure add the `[AllowAnonymous]` on your `Index` action in the `HomeController`. And your `LoginPath` is `/Home/Index`, it is no need to be authorized.

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        //do your stuff...
        return View();            
    }
    //....
}
```

**Update:**

Cookie authentication to login

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Login/LoginView";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Login/AccessDenied";
});
        
var app = builder. Build();
       
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();   //be sure add authentication and authorization middleware.....
app.UseAuthorization();

//...
```

How to sigh in the user:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginView(string username, string password)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        //Error code here
     }
        
     if (!UserExists(username, password))//Check if user exists in Database
     {
        //Error code here
     }                      
    var claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,username)   //add the claims you want...
    };
    //authProperties you can choose any option you want, below is a sample...
    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        //IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        //ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        //IsPersistent = false
    };
    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), authProperties);

    TempData["Username"] = username;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    
}
```

Comment: I know it solves one problem but still, the user can not access other authorized controllers and action methods. Because he is not authorized. Also if I set LoginPath as /Home/Index the landing page becomes the home page, not the login page. also, default route is /Home/Index mentioned in middleware.

Comment: Hi @BabarHussain, if this original problem has been solved, suggest you can accept the answer which can let others quickly find the solution. For the new problem, pls post a new thread to explain how do the user login and share the detailed code because cannot access the authorized action is caused by user unauthenticated or unauthorized. Thanks.

Comment: I would surely accept the answer but it does not exactly provide the solution. [AllowAnonymous] on Index action in the HomeController is not a good approach since the user hasn't been validated. The user must be validated to access any other controllers or action methods.

Comment: I think you do not understand the error. Your login path is impossible be authorized. Because If a method declared with authorize, it needs to be authorized and the project will redirect to the login path to login. For your login path is Home/Index, so it will always redirect the User to the login path.

Comment: My Mistake I had used the wrong login path in the program.cs file is now corrected. The home controller is the path to show after successful login from Login/LoginView.

Comment: So you need share how do you want to login, by cookie authentication or Identity, your code always redirect to Index action of course it will always give you too many times redirect, so that is why I give you add the [AllowAnonymous] attribute for your current issue.  Any way I update the answer and give how cookie authentication works you could check.